# Using Beautiful Soup On Stock Tracker

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from Robintrack but, I cannot get the data from the increase/decrease section. I can only scrape the home page data. Here is my Soup

```
import bs4
import requests
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

robin_track_url= 'https://robintrack.net/popularity_changes?changeType=increases'
#r = requests.get('https://robintrack.net/popularity_changes?changeType=increases')
#soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "xml")


#Grabs and downloads html page
uClient = uReq(robin_track_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#Does HTML parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

print("On Page")

print(page_soup.body)

stocks = page_soup.body.findAll("div", {"class":"ReactVirtualized__Table__row"})

print(len(stocks))
print(stocks)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version not will be work because the data that you want to load is loaded via JS.
requests load the only static page.
if you want to get data that you want to do next:

```
requests.get('https://robintrack.net/api/largest_popularity_increases?hours_ago=24&limit=50&percentage=false&min_popularity=50&start_index=0').json()
```